# react-google-maps resets map when using onClick events

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps, react-google-maps

I'm having difficulty implementing some simple react-google-maps code where whenever a marker is clicked or an info box is closed, the map will reset its position to the original position. I saw that I should be rendering the map component separately from changing the state, but I'm not sure how to implement this.

Any help is appreciated

````
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Marker, GoogleMap,LoadScript,InfoWindow} from '@react-google-maps/api';


const MapContainer = ({markers}) => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState<any>({})

    const onSelect = (item) => {
        setSelected(item)
    }

    const mapStyles = {
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100%",
    }

    const defaultCenter = {
        lat: 45.510440, lng: -122.683338
    }

    const renderMap = () => {
    return <>
        <div>
            <LoadScript
                googleMapsApiKey='[GOOGLE API KEY]'>
                <GoogleMap
                    mapContainerStyle={mapStyles}
                    zoom={13}
                    center={defaultCenter}
                    >

                {markers.map((marker)=> {
                    return(
                    <Marker 
                        position={{
                            lat: marker.lat,
                            lng: marker.lng
                        }}
                        title={marker.title}
                        onClick={ () => onSelect(marker) }
                    />
                )})
                }
                {
                    selected.lng &&
                    <InfoWindow
                    position={
                        {
                            lat: selected.lat,
                            lng: selected.lng
                        }
                    }
                    onCloseClick={() => setSelected({})}
                    >
                        <div>
                        <h3>{selected.title}</h3>
                        <p>{selected.info}</p>
                        </div>
                    </InfoWindow>
                }

                </GoogleMap>
            </LoadScript>
        </div>
    </>
    }

    return renderMap()
}

export default MapContainer; ```
````

Comment: Please remove your API key from the code and change this in the Google API console, otherwise it will be used by others.

Comment: Omg thank you for catching that!

Comment: You're welcome. I've done things like that before too. Don't forget to change it in the console. Sites like these are likely scraped for API keys like that.

Comment: @WillWalsh The key is still visible in the history of your post (which is publicly available). In case you don't use that key anymore, no need to bother.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that putting your center value in a state and setting the clicked marker coordinates as the new center will solve the issue. Here's a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-aefyd2?file=index.tsx) and  a code snippet:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Marker, GoogleMap,LoadScript,InfoWindow} from '@react-google-maps/api';
import { render } from "react-dom";
import markers from "./data.json"
const MapContainer = () => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState<any>({})
    const [center,setCenter]= useState({
        lat: 39.952584, lng: -75.165221
    })

    const onSelect = (item) => {
        setSelected(item)
        setCenter({
        lat: item.lat, lng: item.lng
    })
    }

    const mapStyles = {
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100%",
    }


    const renderMap = () => {
    return <>
        <div>
            <LoadScript
                googleMapsApiKey='AIzaSyBlfuRgAUDPGJnUpwyyhdSBIs193bXboMQ'>
                <GoogleMap
                    mapContainerStyle={mapStyles}
                    zoom={13}
                    center={center}
                    >

                {markers.map((marker,i)=> {
                    return(
                    <Marker 
                    key={i}
                        position={{
                            lat: marker.lat,
                            lng: marker.lng
                        }}
                        title={marker.title}
                        onClick={ () => onSelect(marker) }
                    />
                )})
                }
                {
                    selected.lng &&
                    <InfoWindow
                    position={
                        {
                            lat: selected.lat,
                            lng: selected.lng
                        }
                    }
                    onCloseClick={() => setSelected({})}
                    >
                        <div>
                        <h3>{selected.id}</h3>
                        <p>{selected.name}</p>
                        </div>
                    </InfoWindow>
                }

                </GoogleMap>
            </LoadScript>
        </div>
    </>
    }

    return renderMap()
}


render(<MapContainer />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: This indeed in the answer and it works. Verified :)

Answer (score 1):

Put the center in a state and set it to null after tiles are loaded, like this:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Marker, GoogleMap,LoadScript,InfoWindow} from '@react-google-maps/api';


const MapContainer = ({markers}) => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState<any>({})

    const onSelect = (item) => {
        setSelected(item)
    }

    const mapStyles = {
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100%",
    }

    const defaultCenter = {
        lat: 45.510440, lng: -122.683338
    }
    const [center, setCenter] = useState(defaultCenter)


    const renderMap = () => {
    return <>
        <div>
            <LoadScript
                googleMapsApiKey='[GOOGLE API KEY]'>
                <GoogleMap
                    mapContainerStyle={mapStyles}
                    zoom={13}
                    center={center}
                    onTilesLoaded={() => setCenter(null)}
                    >

                {markers.map((marker)=> {
                    return(
                    <Marker 
                        position={{
                            lat: marker.lat,
                            lng: marker.lng
                        }}
                        title={marker.title}
                        onClick={ () => onSelect(marker) }
                    />
                )})
                }
                {
                    selected.lng &&
                    <InfoWindow
                    position={
                        {
                            lat: selected.lat,
                            lng: selected.lng
                        }
                    }
                    onCloseClick={() => setSelected({})}
                    >
                        <div>
                        <h3>{selected.title}</h3>
                        <p>{selected.info}</p>
                        </div>
                    </InfoWindow>
                }

                </GoogleMap>
            </LoadScript>
        </div>
    </>
    }

    return renderMap()
}

export default MapContainer;
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the only thing that worked for me.